# Why do I need Cordova plugins to integrate GTM into an Ionic app?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, google-tag-manager

I'm building an Ionic hybrid app (Web, Android, iOS), and I want to integrate Google Tag Manager into it.

Now my ratio was - "This is just a regular Web SPA, Cordova just adds a wrapper when you want to compile it for Mobile and that's it" (in a nutshell).

So my idea was to just integrate GTM just I would do for a regular Web SPA, and that would work on Mobile too.

But then, I saw various Cordova packages for Firebase, GTM, Google Analytics etc, and that got me wondering - why do I need them, or do I need them in order to integrate GTM normally? A lot of tutorials exist to help you through the process, but I still don't understand why do you need Cordova plugins in order for your analytics to work on Web and Mobile too - considering this is just a wrapped Web SPA.